# Printers overview shows "Ready" for all printers, though they are on a different network

Tags: printing

The top printer in the list is at a club I used to go to. That printer has been taken down at least a month ago. The second printer on the list is at work.

[image]

Currently I am connected to the wifi hotspot on my cell phone, and still both printers are shown as "Ready".

First of all, I would like to know what that means? Is this the expected behavior? I would expect something like "Not available".

Furthermore, if I try to delete these printers, they disappear from the list, and then reappear after approximately 5 seconds.

If I actually do connect the the network at work, and then try to print, the job gets added to the queue but then nothing more happens.

What is going on?

**Ubuntu Version**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: `apt purge cups-browsed`. What is shown now?

Comment: After restarting the one printer that I tried deleting is not indeed gone. I ran your apt command and restarted, but he one printer left in the overview still shows as "Ready" even though the machine was taken down a month ago.